# Python Request Post - Wont login

Tags: python, logging, http-post

[image]I'm trying to login trough requests post method. i took a screen shot of the parameter value of post requests from firefox

```
import requests
params = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmail': 'someusr', 
          'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPwd': 'somepswrd'}
r = requests.post('https://somewebsite.com/login.aspx', data=params, verify=True)
print(r.text)
```

any idea why the code above wont log me in

Comment: What is the exact error you are facing? Are you sure that the data is correct?

Comment: Check out [requests Basic Auth](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)